# Ismember, multiple times

Tags: matlab

I have an array of letters

```
mystring = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
```

and I have the word `Elephant`. I want to know how many times the letters appear in `Elephant`. I have tried `ismember` and it gives me if they appear but not how many times. How can I get the number of times a letter occurs in a word?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html):

```
mystring = 'bcdfgijkmoqrsuvwxyzelphant';
myword = 'elephant';

[sortstring, idx] = sort(mystring); % Bin edges for histcounts need to be increasing

N = histcounts(double(myword), [double(sortstring) 257]); % Add 257 to the array so we capture the last character in a bin
N(idx) = N; % Undo the sort
```

Which returns:

```
N =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     2     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Note that due to the conversion to ASCII this method is case sensitive. You can adjust for this using [`lower`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lower.html) or [`upper`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/upper.html), if necessary.

Comment: Was about to write the same, just with a different first line: `alphabet=char(['A':'Z','a':'z']);`

Comment: @Daniel, that works too. I was aiming for something more generic.

Answer (score 1):

```
mystring = char(['A':'Z','a':'z']);
Alphabet = zeros(numel(mystring),1);
for ii = 1:numel(mystring)
    Alphabet(ii,1) = sum(ismember('Elephant',mystring(ii)));
end
```

`ismember` checks whether the current letter of the alphabet as dictated by the loop exists in the word. If it does, it sums all occurrences to obtain the total occurrence times of each letter, stored in `Alphabet`, where each entry corresponds to the letter at that position in the alphabet.

I used the method of creating the alphabet as per [@Daniel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544936/ismember-multiple-times/33545151#comment54870420_33545385); capitals do now work.

Example, test for `William Shakespeare`:

```
Alphabet.'

ans =

  Columns 1 through 15

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 16 through 30

     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     3     0     0     0

  Columns 31 through 45

     3     0     0     1     2     0     1     2     1     0     0     1     0     1     1

  Columns 46 through 52

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```